# Direct render in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, 2d, render, sprite-kit

I am making a tile based game for iOS using SpriteKit 
All the game logic were made inside classes and I just want to render them with SpriteKit.
The problem is that using the simulator in MacPro, the FPS is about 60.0 and the game is ok.
But in my iPod the FPS is around 5 and the Timer that control player/mobs movements works very slow, even without delay.

In the game scene:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
        [self removeAllChildren];
        for(NSMutableArray *tiles in [TileManager sharedInstance].tiles)
        {
            for(Tile *tile in tiles)
            {
                if(tile.tile)
                {
                    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [self newSprite: tile.tile.__sprite];
                    sprite.position = [tile getGlobalPosWithFrame: self.frame];
                    sprite.size = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_TILE_X, SCREEN_TILE_Y);
                    [self addChild: sprite];
                }
                if(tile.item)
                {
                    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [self newSprite: tile.item.__sprite];
                    sprite.position = [tile getGlobalPosWithFrame: self.frame];
                    sprite.size = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_TILE_X, SCREEN_TILE_Y);
                    [self addChild: sprite];
                }
            }
        }
        // ... render creatures, mobs, and other things...
}
```

I've used in the past (many years ago) Andorra2D in Delphi 7
And there I could direct draw sprites in the onUpdate function and even use sprite sheets for animations.
How can I direct draw on SpriteKit, without using SKSpriteNode and all It heavy logic/classes ?

Comment: Wait, so your creating a new sprite every 1/60 of a second? Also, are you not taking delta into account?

Comment: I don't think your code sample is accurately portraying the whole picture. As Roecrew asked, it appears you are creating a lot of new sprites in the update method. What is the reason for this?

Comment: I am recreating the sprites every time a new frame is being rendered.
This is because I want to render the sprites according to my Tile/Map/Creature classes and it properties/positions.
If a creature die, or a item is destroyed/taken, it is not rendered anymore. I don't want to destroy the correct node object, it would mess all the game logic.
I want to SpriteKit only render my game, not help me to code.

Comment: Well, that's a waste of processing power.

Comment: But it works this way in lot of other graphic libs/renders. 

Adding childs to render would be better if optional :( 

What can be done in my case ?

Comment: You can use other ways to do this. For example, use contacts to check for 2 objects touching (player and bullet). Based on contacts and checking positions, you can change a sprite's texture or animation accordingly.

Comment: have a look at (or just use) the optimized tilemap renderer of Kobold Kit: https://github.com/KoboldKit/KoboldKit/tree/master/KoboldKit/KoboldKitFree/Framework/Nodes/Tilemap

Comment: @sangony But my game do not use collisions, nor bullets.
My classes are already made, I don't want to redo everything inside SpriteKit, I wanted it to only render my things, I don't want to be SpriteKit-dependent. But unfortunately at the same time if my project do not use SpriteKit, it will not be approved in my class.

Comment: Fair enough but you will need to expand on what you are trying to accomplish and show some code too. I think there is a solution to your issue but it requires more information on your part. How do your creatures die? How is an item destroyed or taken? Etc...

Comment: Look this SS: http://prntscr.com/3d4krg
All this classes manages the game and the class Game has the main loop and the timer.
I coded the Bomberman remake, the basis is ok, bombing, taking bonuses, breaking boxes, killing creatures/players, kicking the bombs.
This is why I don't wanted to change nothing, only use SpriteKit to render, not to control the game logic.

Comment: That is all very nice but obviously you HAVE to make changes due to your low FPS.

Comment: Do you know if SpriteKit have a canvas-like render or any other mature graphic engine ?

Comment: You have to use node classes in Sprite Kit, there is no "direct draw" as in using OpenGL commands directly. And quite frankly the performance of Sprite Kit isn't the problem, it's your code design that makes it slow. It's not even the drawing that's slow, it's the fact that you keep creating new sprites. Cache those sprites and change their textures and other properties as needed.